# Measure Total Information About a System

Tags: correlation, optimization, matrix

Say I have a correlation matrix that measures how well certain components in a system track each other along some meaningful dimension, like condition state:

[image]

So, for example, component 1 and component 2 have condition states that track 80% but component 1 and 3 are not related at all.

I want to perform some inspection on a subset of those, with the hope that I can gain some information about the larger system as a whole without inspecting everything.

In an ideal situation, I could inspect everything, where an inspection vector, `[I]`, is `1` when a component is inspected `[I] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` and the total information is 100%.

Assume I have an assigned cost to inspect each component; I'd like to set up an optimization problem to assign `[I]` with the goal to get as close as possible to 100% information within a budget constraint. I'm not sure if there's a way to logically set up matrix operations to do this.

Comment: Based on this description I can't be sure but the problem sounds similar to a Six Sigma quality assessment. For example, http://statvision.com/quality_assessment.htm